# Mounting error while installing VM ware tools in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, vmware, kali-linux

I have installed Kali Linux on VM Workstation.I want to install the VM tools but when I click "install VMware tools" from the VM workstation menu I receive this error at the guest OS window "unable to mount VM ware tools error mounting:mount exited with with exit code 1:...." 
Does any on know what's the problem here and how I can proceed with the installation.

Answer (score 2):

The vmware tools are normally injected by inserting a virtual install medium into the guest system. If your guest machine has no CD device, this could fail.

As an alternative, you may be able to install vmware tools from the package manager of your distribution with some command along the lines of

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

instead of via the VMWare workstation menu.

If this does not work instantly, you may have to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the following lines

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
```

Comment: I read that CDs are not necessary to install the tools and I found one Youtube guy doing it but it fails for me from the beginning of the steps...

Comment: I tried that line but no luck it says "Package 'open-vm-tools' has no installation candidate

Comment: @user2309720 - You might be missing the entries to get this packae in your sources.list. I think this shows how to add them: http://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?92-How-to-install-Open-Vm-tools-correctly

Comment: @slm I'm still getting the same error when I click "install VMware tools" from the VM workstation menu.

Comment: @XZS I also have tried that before but seems no to work buddy!!!